# .pop() not working in browser cosole, why?

Tags: javascript, console

When I'm trying to `console.log(this.pop())` in the browser console it's showing this error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.pop is not a function
> at :1:6

Is there any way to make it working?

Hope you can help me

Comment: Possibly because `this` is not an array. Can't tell for certain without knowing, what `this` is.

Comment: `this` points to the window of the current website you are on.

Comment: Why would the window object have a pop method?

Comment: Also `this` can be a lot of things depending on the context, it's not always the window

Comment: As you see i was experimenting with the browser console and wanted to see what would pop method would do to `this` which is an object called window.

Comment: ...and the browser told you that there is no `pop` method for that object, how does that not answer that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pop()` is a method found in the `Array.prototype` and the `globalThis` is an object

> `pop` method can be called or applied to objects resembling arrays. Objects which do not contain a `length` property reflecting the last in a series of consecutive, zero-based numerical properties may not behave in any meaningful manner.

Comment: @DanielDominic Don't care about it. Keep going and ask more questions. Welcome to StackOverflow. If this answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also, see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.